# Python & ML - I need help creating a nested dictionary from a given dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning

I have a dataset like

```
NAME  1-pt 1-time 2-pt 2-time ...
abc   xyz  2345   def  2200
```

I need to make a nested dictionary like

{abc:{xyz:2345, def:2200}...}

I need a dictionary like NAME:{1-pt:1-time, 2-pt:2-time} format with the dataset
how do I do this?

I tried
df.set_index('NAME').to_dict(orient='dict') but that did not give me the desired results. What other way can I do this?

Comment: Can you specify the format of your dataset.Is it a csv file or an xls file or a dataframe?

Comment: The dataset is a csv file

Comment: Please do accept as the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method in the regular `dict()` to achieve this:

```
import csv
new_data_dict = {}
with open("test.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        item = new_data_dict.get(row["NAME"], dict())
        item[row["1-pt"]] = int(row["1-time"])
        item[row["2-pt"]] = int(row["2-time"])
        new_data_dict[row["NAME"]] = item

print(new_data_dict)
```

This gives your required output that is:

```
{'abc': {'xyz': 2345, 'def': 2200}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic way to do this you can try using `iter` and a dict comprehension to generate it.

```
d = dict()
with open("yourfile") as f:
     next(f) # skip the 1st line as its a header
     for line in f:
         line = line.strip().split("\t") # change the split to whatever you want
         it = iter(line[1:])
         d[line[0]] = {x:next(it) for x in it}
```

It doesn't take in consideration how many columns you have and will fail if you have for instance something like this (missing a the value `3-time` column here):

```
NAME   1-pt  1-time 2-pt 2-time 3-pt
abc   xyz    2345   def  2200   foo
```

Same it won't work if you have columns which are not key followed by the value as it works by simply iterating over a pair of columns putting the 1st as the key and the second as value.

If you know the the value will always be a number you can encapsulate the `next(it)` with something like `int(next(it))`

EDIT: Output with my test file

*Test file*

```
NAME    1-pt    1-time  2-pt    2-time  3-pt    3-time
abc     xyz     2345    def     2200    pfout   564655
def     uvw     9999    flop    7777    pong    11111
```

*Output*

```
{'abc': {'xyz': '2345', 'def': '2200', 'pfout': '564655'}, 'def': {'uvw': '9999', 'flop': '7777', 'pong': '11111'}}
```